# Updating data in a table in test db from a table in live db in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-update, insert-update

I have same table in testDB and liveDB. I need to update the data in the testDB with the data in the LiveDB for that table. How to do this in Oracle?

Comment: do you need to update the data and keep the testdb data or do you simply need to replace the data in test with live?  if the later, then truncate testdb table, export the table from live with oracle exp and imp table into testdb with imp using the fromuser/touser to get it into the schema you want if they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Oracle `merge` command:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9016.htm

It will combine all the `inserts`, `updates` and `deletes` to make the records identical. That should work, unless you have some referential integrity check with other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is data in test that has to be kept, run a scheduled script to :

```
DELETE * FROM TESTDATA_TBL
```

then

```
INSERT INTO TESTDATA_TBL (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, . . . ) 
SELECT LIVEDATA_TBL.COLUMN1, LIVEDATA_TBL.COLUMN2 FROM LIVEDATA_TBL
```

etc.